# Are float arrays always aligned to 16 byte boundaries?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

My understanding is that you have to explicitly specify the alignment of an array, if you want it aligned.

However, the float arrays I declare always seem to be aligned to 16 byte.

```
float *ptr1 = new float[1];
cout<<"ptr1: "<<ptr1<<endl;
float *ptr2 = new float[3];
cout<<"ptr2: "<<ptr2<<endl;
float arr1[7];
cout<<"arr1: "<<arr1<<endl;
float arr2[9] __attribute__((aligned(2)));
cout<<"arr2: "<<arr2<<endl;
```

Here is the output

```
ptr1: 0x13dc010
ptr2: 0x13dc030
arr1: 0x7fff874885c0
arr2: 0x7fff87488590
```

Is there a reason for this? I am using gcc 4.6.3

However if it's a pointer to a float location or statically allocated, I don't see it

```
static float arr3[9] __attribute__((aligned(2)));
cout<<"arr3: "<<arr3<<endl;
float *x;
cout<<"x: "<<x<<endl;
```

Output:

```
arr3: 0x4030b2
x: 0x7fff8c7dd9e8
```

This code was run on x64.

Comment: It depends on your compiler. Look at their documentation. P.S. Your `float *x` is never initialized so the results from that are basically random.

Comment: My gcc 4.8.1 only aligns to 8 bytes by default. That's because the `malloc` implementation does this (...which `operator new` calls). In one word: don't count on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alignment requirements are determined by each compiler, influenced by hardware requirements and any relevant [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface).

The C and C++ languages discuss alignment for types, but they don't impose any specific requirements (except that, for example, a structure's alignment is at least the alignment of any of its members). A valid implementation could permit all data types to be byte aligned, or it could require each scalar type to be aligned to its own size (the latter is more common). Intermediate alignments are possible, such as aligning 8-byte types on 4-byte boundaries.

On the x86 in particular, aligning scalars to their size makes for more efficient access, but misaligned accesses still work correctly, though a little more slowly.

The *required* alignment for an array of `float` is the same as the required alignment for a single `float` object. If `float` is 4 bytes, then that alignment can be no greater than 4 bytes, since arrays do not have gaps between their elements.

A particular compiler might choose to impose stricter alignment on array objects, as you've (probably) seen, if it makes access to those objects a little more efficient.

And if the `new` operator is implemented by calling `malloc`, then all `new`-allocated objects will have an alignment strict enough for any type.

If `float` arrays are always aligned to 16-byte boundaries, it's because your compiler chooses to do allocate them that way, not because it's required by the language. On the other hand, if  you use aliasing to force a `float` array to a 4-byte alignment (assuming `sizeof (float) == 4`), then accesses to that array and to its elements should still work correctly.

Incidentally, when I run your code (after wrapping it in a `main` program) on my x86_64 system, I get results similar to yours. When I run it on an x86 system, I get:

```
ptr1: 0x9e34008
ptr2: 0x9e34018
arr1: 0xbfefa160
arr2: 0xbfefa17c
```

I'm using gcc under Linux on both systems.

So the straightforward answer to your question is no, `float` arrays are not always aligned to 16-byte boundaries.

But in most cases there's no particular reason for you to care. Unless you play aliasing tricks (treating an object of some declared type as if it were of another type), the compiler will always give each object *at least* the alignment it needs for correct access.

Comment: I am using some SSE in my project. So I guess, I should explicity specify the alignment to 16 bytes and not rely on my compiler to do it for me. I ran it on x64. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I haven't used SSE myself; I don't know what the proper way is to specify the required alignment in that case. You probably would have gotten more useful information if you had asked how to use SSE rather than a more generic question about alignment. Ask about the problem your actually trying to solve. And a Google search for "SSE alignment" gets a lot of results; I'll let you look through them yourself.

Comment: I have the code running, just wanted to make sure that alignment has to be specified explicitly. SSE floating point operations require a 16 byte alignment. I have a performance critical section in my project.

Comment: @Mathai: It may be working just by coincidence. You need advice either from someone who's familiar with SSE, and with gcc's interaction with it, or from some actual documentation. I answered the question you asked; you need to do some more research, and possibly post a new question, that's specifically about SSE and alignment.

Comment: You might want to care about alignment when, for example, declaring the fields in a class. Improper order can result in much larger objects than needed. We're talking 30% larger. It might not matter for most small programs, but if you have millions of objects of that type, the wasted space adds up. Plus, it will take longer to do some operations like copy. That can slow things down if you do millions of copies. But you're right that you don't have to think about it to write it so that it compiles with the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but if you want a larger size I suggest using the type "double" instead of "float". "Float" generally has a size limit of 4 bytes (about 7 digits) whereas "double" usually has a size limit of 8 bytes (about 15 digits).

EDIT: Sorry, I misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

That depend on most strict fundamental type alignment requirement of the platform like long double, which is 16 byte alignment require for my Debian 64 system.
The stack frame alignment maybe impact by this too.